# Finereader recognizes multiple tables in the image as a single table block in the layout

Tags: abbyy, finereader

How to identify and separate the one table block to multiple table blocks with C# ?

My idea would be recognizing table headers and logically try and split table blocks. Is there any better way to separate tables ? also, Is there a way to draw new table blocks and regions in a new FRPage with data of existing blocks ?

[image: Results of image recognition with two different params with FineReader SDK 12]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following way:

1. Process all pixel lines in your image one by one
2. In case if there are only white pixels in the certain line, count this line as custom table separator
3. Divide your page into a few custom analysis blocks by the custom table separators
4. Call AnalyzeRegion Method of the FRPage Object for each custom analysis block
5. Call FRPage.Recognize

Comment: Hi, I do not find any reference to 'Pixel Line' in FR SDK 12 documentation

Comment: It is not there. SDK is called "SDK" because you are expected to write your application code.

Comment: This looks like a very smart solution to me !